# Wpf animations from code

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

There was some similar threads, but I didn't find solution of my problem. It's my first post here.
Here's the thing:

```cs
Viewport3D viewPort3D;

GeometryModel3D geometryModel = new GeometryModel3D();  
Transform3DGroup transform3DGroup = new Transform3DGroup();

...

// Rotation
RotateTransform3D rotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D();   
AxisAngleRotation3D axisAngleRotation3d = new AxisAngleRotation3D();  
axisAngleRotation3d.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);  
axisAngleRotation3d.Angle = angle;  
rotateTransform3D.Rotation = axisAngleRotation3d;  
transform3DGroup.Children.Add(rotateTransform3D);  

// Translation  
TranslateTransform3D translateTransform3D = new TranslateTransform3D();  
translateTransform3D.OffsetX = offsetX;
transform3DGroup.Children.Add(translateTransform3D);  

// Adding transforms  
geometryModel.Transform = transform3DGroup;  

Model3DGroup model3DGroup = new Model3DGroup();
model3DGroup.Children.Add( image.getGeometryModel3D() );

modelVisual3D.Content = model3DGroup;
viewPort3D.Children.Add( modelVisual3D );
```

And now I want to make translation using storyboard (because later I want to add also rotating to that storyboard):

```cs
Storyboard s = new Storyboard();

Transform3DGroup transform3DGroup = model3DGroup.Children.ElementAt(current).Transform as Transform3DGroup;

for (int j = 0; j < transform3DGroup.Children.Count; ++j)
{
   if (transform3DGroup.Children.ElementAt(j) is TranslateTransform3D)
   {
      TranslateTransform3D translation = transform3DGroup.Children.ElementAt(j) as TranslateTransform3D;

      DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
      doubleAnimation.From = 0;
      doubleAnimation.To = 2;
      doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      doubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
      doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

      s.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
      s.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

      Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, model3DGroup.Children.ElementAt(current));
      Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Model3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetX)"));

      s.Begin(); // Exception during the execution.
   }
}
```

Exception in the last line:

> '[Unknown]' property value in the path
>   '(Model3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetX)'
>   points to immutable instance of
>   'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.TranslateTransform3D'.

I took PropertyPath similar to the path generated in blend 4.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because translate tranform 3d is an immutable instance it has to be indicated that it should be mutable while rendering / translation is taking place.

I guess

1. We can supply `x:Name` to that immutable `TranslateTransform3D` object, to make it mutable.
2. Bind to its property than to animate it.

E.g. in your case

```
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());
        this.RegisterName("AxisRotation", MyAxisRotation3DObject.Rotation);
        this.RegisterName("TranslateTransformation", MyTranslation3DObject);
```

This way we give names to Axis Rotation 3D and Translate Transform 3D objects and then in double animations refer them as `Storyboard.SetTargetName(.., "AxisRotation")` and `Storyboard.SetTargetName(.., "TranslateTransformation")` and access their direct properties such as `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(.., new PropertyPath("Angle"))` and `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(.., new PropertyPath("OffsetX"))` resp.

Comment: Yes! It's working. Only need to remember to use s.Begin(this); Thank you. Could you write shortly how to bind this property?

Answer (score 0):

Your error states that `TranslateTransform3D` is immutable, what means, it cannot be changed. And you're trying to animate one of its properties, hence got the error.

Comment: Now I get Exception: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'TranslateTransform3D.OffsetX'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.
And with 
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath("(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetX)"));
nothing happens.